Existence of a Maximum for a Function on $\mathbb{R}_{++}^3$
I am currently examining whether the function defined by
$$
f(x) = -\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \ln x_i
$$
for $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^3$ subject to the constraint $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$ possesses a maximum. Initially, I contemplated applying Lagrange multipliers to solve this constrained optimization problem, but uncertainties regarding the existence of a maximum remained.
The function $f$ appears to be concave and continuous. However, the domain $\mathbb{R}_{++}^3$ is not compact, precluding a direct application of the Weierstrass Theorem to guarantee the existence of a maximum.
Could someone provide guidance or suggest a method to verify whether a maximum exists for this function under the given constraints?

What is $\mathbb{R}^3_{++}$?

it is $\mathbb{R}^3_+ - {0}$.

Try substituting $x_3 = 1 -x_1-x_2 $, and checking if any point with $x_1+x_2 < 1$ satisfies the first-order condition of optimality.

You can extend the function to $\mathbb{R}^3_+$ by continuity ($-x \ln(x) \rightarrow 0$ when $x \rightarrow 0$). Then, the intersection of $\mathbb{R}^3_+$ with the plane $\{x_1+x_2+x_3=1\}$ is compact, so you can apply the Weierstrass theorem. 
(sorry for this short answer, i dont have enough rep to comment)

But the function is not defined at $0$, your argument shows not being closed of the set?

You can extend the function to $0$ by continuity ($−x \ln(x)→0$ when $x→0$)
(thanks to the person who upvoted me, I can now comment!)

But this is the same as you have written before. I could not get how to extend a function to the point at which it is undefined.

Calculate the limit and see that it converges to $0$, and thus can be extended by continuity.

Then the theorem's compactness part becomes redundant because as soon as we have a continuous function, we can extend it. Am I wrong?

No because you can't extend every continuous function, it is case by case
